# Implementing editor template for two listboxes with add/remove items functionality

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have many pages in my application which have two listboxes with add/remove items option. If list1 is source, list2 is destination, I need only items from list2 (newlyadded/removed items). So was wondering how to design the editor template. Below are my initial thoughts, could anyone see issues (or) provide suggestions to make it better.

1. Create a int[] property in viewmodel which holds all list2 id's.
2. Create a editor template for this property and create a listbox with items of specified id's. Since list1 source can be anything or can be populated by various methods like AJAX, so preferred to include only list2 in the editor template.
3. Write a javascript functions inside the editor template, to add newitem to it and if removed, provide the item to source. And to provide the modifications when submitted, add function creates hidden fields in the DOM and deletes them when item is removed.

Note: They are not listboxes they are telerik grid controls, for simplicity I mentioned listboxes but I would just need id's of listbox2 though. So, I think listbox or gridview doesn't make difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an application with almost identical behavior and chose the same technique.  However, my ViewModel contained both the List1 and List2.

Calling my editor template was done like this:

```
    <div id="SoftwarePanel" class="collapsiblePanel">
        <h2>Request Software</h2>
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Software)
    </div>
```

"Software" in this case was an instance of a "RequestableList" class containing properties for "AvailableItems" and "RequestedItems".  The editor template rendered both lists adjacent to each other, placed appropriate buttons for moving items back and forth between the listboxes and wired up the javascript.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="avail@{@name}Filter" />
            <button type="button" id="avail@{@name}Clear" class="DualList_availClear dualListButton"">
                X</button><br />
            @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.AvailableItems, new MultiSelectList((from i in Model.AvailableItems where !Model.RequestedItems.Contains(i.Key) select i), "Key", "Value"), new { @class = "dualList" })
            <br />
            <span id="avail@{@name}Counter" class="countLabel"></span>
            <select id="avail@{@name}Storage">
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button id="to2@{@name}" type="button" class="dualListButton">
                &gt;</button><br />
            <button id="allTo2@{@name}" type="button" class="dualListButton">
                &gt;&gt;</button><br />
            <button id="allTo1@{@name}" type="button" class="DualList_Allto1 dualListButton">
                &lt;&lt;</button><br />
            <button id="to1@{@name}" type="button" class="dualListButton">
                &lt;</button><br />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="@{@name}RequestedFilter" />
            <button type="button" id="@{@name}RequestedClear" class="DualList_requestClear dualListButton">
                X</button><br />
            @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.RequestedItems, new MultiSelectList((from i in Model.RequestedItems select new { key = i, value = Model.AvailableItems[i] }).AsEnumerable(), "key", "value"), new { @class = "dualList" })
            <br />
            <span id="@{@name}RequestedCounter" class="countLabel"></span>
            <select id="@{@name}RequestedStorage">
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

UPDATE: I used the DualListBox plugin developed by Justin Mead.  http://www.meadmiracle.com/dlb/DLBDocumentation.aspx

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $.configureBoxes({
                box1View: '@ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId("AvailableItems")',
                box1Storage: 'avail@{@name}Storage',
                box1Filter: 'avail@{@name}Filter',
                box1Clear: 'avail@{@name}Clear',
                box1Counter: 'avail@{@name}Counter',
                box2View: '@ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId("RequestedItems")',
                box2Storage: '@{@name}RequestedStorage',
                box2Filter: '@{@name}RequestedFilter',
                box2Clear: '@{@name}RequestedClear',
                box2Counter: '@{@name}RequestedCounter',
                to1: 'to1@{@name}',
                to2: 'to2@{@name}',
                allTo1: 'allTo1@{@name}',
                allTo2: 'allTo2@{@name}',
                onItemsChanged: function () {
                    var opts = $('#@ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId("RequestedItems") option');
                    var optIds = $.map(opts, function(e) { return $(e).val(); });
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: @Shwan, thanks for sharing your approach. I may not be able to wireup both in one since source list is varying page by page. Can you please post your javascript, if possible.

Comment: I don't see how the source list varying by page would cause a problem.  Wouldn't the action rendering the view simply load different data into the viewmodel when sending to the view to render?  In my case, I actually had 4 different "RequestableItem" properties in my view model.  Each with a different source.

Comment: It does load the data but user can populate the data via ajax into the source list. As I mentioned, its not the listbox, its third party controls so I can't append its "select" event to anything particular. It differs page to page.